# Differentiable function- prove that there exists a point such that $ f'(\lambda)=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $ f:(I)\rightarrow R $ is differentiable and show if $ f(x)=f(y)=0 $ for $ a<x<y<b $ then there exists $ x < \lambda<y $ such that $ f'(\lambda)=0 $.

I was thinking to use the following theorem: Suppose $ f $ is a real differentiable function on $[a,b] $ and suppose $ f'(a)<\lambda <f'(b) $. Then there is a point $ x\in (a,b) $ such that $ f'(x)=\lambda $.

but I don't think it's as straightforward as I think.. any ideas?

Comment: Have you covered Rolle's theorem in class?

Comment: No, not unless what I wrote is Rolle's theorem

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what Rolle's theorem tells.

Comment: I didn't know that! To prove it, could I use the theorem I wrote above? Or is there another way ( I keep getting stuck)

Comment: The theorem you are referring to is Darboux's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is just [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that. Could I prove it using the theorem I put in the question?

Comment: Hmmm... possibly. I imagine it usually goes the other way though, i.e. Rolle's theorem proves the mean value theorem, which I think is used in the proof of the theorem you stated.

Comment: yes you are right, that theorem uses the mean value theorem in the proof. I'm just learning about differentiation and its hard when I see a claim like this--I don't know where to start going about proving it..I've learned so many theorems; don't know which to apply

Comment: I know, it's a bit like that to start with, but don't worry, you'll get there! If you've learned the mean value theorem you can apply it here directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is Rolle's theorem.

The proof usually goes along the following lines:

Let $R=f([x,y])$, $m=\inf R, M = \sup R$. If $m=M$ then $f$ is constant and so $f'=0$. Otherwise either $m<0$ or $M>0$, we can take $m<0$ without loss of generality (by considering $-f$ if necessary). Since $R$ is compact, there is some $z \in (x,y)$ such that $f(z) = m$ and $f(t) \ge f(z)$ for all $t \in (x,y)$. By considering ${f(z+h)-f(z) \over h}$ for $h>0$ and $h<0$, we have $f'(z) \ge 0$ and $f'(z) \le 0$ and so $f'(z) = 0$.